# Can I query a model with an aggregate count of one of it's association in Ecto?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Is it possible to compose a query that returns all of a model (i.e. Post) with an aggregate count of one of it's associations (i.e. Like).

```
Repo.all(from p in Post, 
    join: l in Like, 
    where l.post_id == p.id,
    group_by: p.id,
    select: {p, count(l.id)
```

I've tried using group_by and select (above), but this only partially works. The results from the query exclude all of posts that don't have any likes.

If this is not possible, what's the best way to handle this problem? First thing that comes to mind mapping over the results of the query like such:

```
posts = 
    Repo.all Post
    |> Enum.map(fn(post) ->
        likes_query = from l in Like, where: l.post_id == ^post.id
        likes_count = Repo.aggregate(likes_query, :count, :id)

        %{post: post, likes_count: likes_count}
     end)
```

Comment: Try changing `join:` to `left_join:` in the first snippet.

Comment: And change `where:` to `on:`.

Comment: @Dogbert Nice! That works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two things wrong with the query:

1. You need to use `on` instead of `where` to specify the join condition
2. You need to use `left_join` instead of `join` if you want posts with no likes to be returned.

Final query:

```
from p in Post, 
  left_join: l in Like, 
  on: l.post_id == p.id,
  group_by: p.id,
  select: {p, count(l.id)}
```

---

You can also use `assoc` in `left_join` here which will add the correct `on` automatically:

```
from p in Post, 
  left_join: l in assoc(p, :likes), 
  group_by: p.id,
  select: {p, count(l.id)}
```

Comment: As a followup, what if I want to also add a third association (i.e. Comments)? I tried the following but the results aren't correct `from p in Post, left_join: l in assoc(p, :likes), left_join: c in assoc(p, :comments), group_by: p.id, select: {p, count(l.id), count(c.id)}`

Comment: I don't think that's possible with joins but I think you can use subqueries for this: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#subquery/1.